# GitHub PagesでCSSが反映されない

Tags: html, css, github-pages

VSCodeで書いたコードを使ってGitHubで自作HPを公開しようとしています。
コードはHTMLとCSSのみ。CSSが反映されずに困っています。
VSCodeのプレビューでは問題なく反映されているのですが、原因がわかりません。

試したこと

１． `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">` を

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://emmaoy.github.io/test_6/css/home.css">
```

に変更。

２．キャッシュのクリア

コードは以下のリンク先です。（画像ファイルが多く見づらくてごめんなさい）
https://github.com/EmmaOY/test_6

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ブラウザの開発者ツールで見るとcssファイルの中身が無いように見えます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

リポジトリ上で実際のファイル構成を見ると、index.html と home.css は同じ階層に存在するので、CSSファイル の指定も以下の様にするべきです。(`css/` のフォルダ指定が余計だった)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://emmaoy.github.io/test_6/home.css">
```

もしくは相対パスでの指定の方が良いかもしれません。

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./home.css">
```